# Query google search engine?

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to query the google search engine by date to get the first page results then process it. The query I am currently using returns results but not in the date range I set; if I copied the same query into google it works for the date but not from my PHP script. The script returns only current or normal results as if the date parameter was not set. part of the code snippet used is below. The query I am referring to is below as well as in the code snippet posted in the $url variable.

Query:`https://www.google.com/search?q='.$Query.'&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2'.$startDate.$EndDate.'&tbm=`

```
$Query= $_POST['Query'];
$Query=str_replace(" ","+",$Query);
if ($_POST['Start_date']==''){
$startday='1';
$startmonth='11';
$startyear='2011';
}
if ($_POST['End_date']==''){
$endday='1';
$endmonth='11';
$endyear='2013';
}
$startDate='Ccd_min%3A'.$startmonth.'%2F'.$startday.'%2F'.$startyear.'.%2';
$EndDate='Ccd_max%3A'.$endmonth.'%2F'.$endday.'%2F'.$endyear.'';

if ($_POST['Query']!=''){
$url  = 'https://www.google.com/search?   
q='.$Query.'&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2'.$startDate.$EndDate.'&tbm=';
echo $url .'<p>';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$searchresults=array();
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
$link   = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }
    array_push($searchresults,$link);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google presents a different html structure to devices without `JavaScript` enabled (`file_get_html($url)`). Temporarily [Disable JavaScript](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0) on chrome and inspect the page. This way you'll be sure to get the correct `div id's`, `classes`, etc to use on your script.

---

## Update based on your comments:

Google doesn't allow searching by date range via direct url if JavaScript is disabled.
Although, you can still use the `daterange` Google operator to find pages that are indexed by Googlebot within the date range specified. The dates submitted must be in the `Julian date` format and the fractions should be omitted for this operator to work properly.

```
Example: daterange:2452671-2452671 lisbon
```

The `daterange` operator requires at least one proper search term and can be combined with other operators.

---

## `gregoriantojd()`

To convert a `Gregorian date` to `Julian date` you can use the php function `gregoriantojd( int $month , int $day , int $year )`, i.e.:

```
$startDate = gregoriantojd(12, 28, 2011);
//2455924

$endDate = gregoriantojd(12, 28, 2014);
//2457020
```

Your search `$url` should look like this:

```
$url = "https://www.google.pt/search?q=lisbon+daterange:2455924-2457020&btnG=Search&num=100&gbv=1"
```

---

## Final code:

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$startDate = gregoriantojd(12, 28, 2011); //2455924
$endDate = gregoriantojd(12, 28, 2014); //2457020
$nResults = "100";
$Query= "lisbon";

$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$Query+daterange:$startDate-$endDate&btnG=Search&num=$nResults&gbv=1";

echo $url .'<p>';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$searchresults=array();
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
$link   = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }
    array_push($searchresults,$link);
}
print_r($searchresults);

/*
Array ( [0] => http://www.cnn.com/2014/01/25/travel/lisbon-coolest-city/ [1] => http://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g189158-Lisbon_Lisbon_District_Central_Portugal-Vacations.html
etc...
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i had an emergency to attend to that is why I could not respond. You are correct when I disable javascript the query no longer  uses the date range i specified, it just returns normal results. Can you suggest a query that might work for date ranges?

Comment: Google datarange: operator accept Julian years, i.e.: `daterange:2451607-2451610 `, can you post an example of the query you used ?

Comment: Query: https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A11%2F1%2F2011.%2Ccd_max%3A11%2F1%2F2013&tbm=

Comment: @user3002303 I'll take a look at it when I arrive home.

Comment: fantastic worked perfectly! My only other issue is how to increase the search results to more than 10 but i will have to ask that as another question ii believe.

Comment: That's great ! If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Tks !

Answer (score 0):

You have **linebreak** inside url in the code you posted:

```
$url  = 'https://www.google.com/search?
q='.$Query.'&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2'.$startDate.$EndDate.'&tbm=';
```

[Linebreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) is usually represened as `LF` character (`0x0D`, on unix-like systems) or `CR`+`LF` characters (`0x0D`+`0x0A`, windows).

Therefore if you have a close look at the url you request, your script send a requst with GET parameter named `%0D%0Aq` insted of `q`.

To corrent this you should put entire two lines above on one line or you cat put linebreak outside string literals, which are strings between each pair of single qoutes in your case e.g (dot at the beginning of the second line makes it easier not to over overlook the two-lined contatenation):

```
$url  = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' 
  . $Query . '&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2' . $startDate . $EndDate . '&tbm=';
```

Comment: that was how it copied and pasted since there are no spaces in the string

Comment: When I copy and paste the echoed URL in google it works but not in the script execution.